# Keep textview beneath image same width as image in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have an image that has a fixed with in dp. Beneath it I have a textview. I have put a constraint on the textview so that the start and end are bound to the image. But if the textview has long text, the width of the textview will grow. Is there a way to keep the width of the textview the same as the image but without setting its width to a fixed value?

Comment: share your code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set textview's width to 0dp, constraintStartToStartOf image, constraintEndToEndOf image. This way its width will match the width of image. Hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try this one
Set textview's width to 0dp, android_layout_weight=1,  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf, app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf.